# How to create a Cumulative count in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Hello I am a beginner in Power BI and would need your help.

I have a data at my end and I need to have Cumulative count of my data based on Month.

| ID | Code | DATE | GENDER | Cumulative Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 5/30/2022 | M | 1 |
| 2 | A | 5/31/2022 | F | 3 |
| 3 | A | 5/31/2022 | M | 3 |
| 4 | A | 6/1/2022 | F | 2 |
| 5 | A | 6/1/2022 | F | 2 |
| 6 | A | 6/2/2022 | M | 3 |

Cumulative Count column above is the output that I am expecting to create in Power BI. Here I have created it manually.

On 30th May total count was 1 then on 31st May count was 2 hence value is 3. Once the month ends and new month starts it should start from 0 and hence on 1st June there are 2 observation and hence total count is 2 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
CALCULATE(
         COUNTROWS('Table')
         ,ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Date])
         ,DATESMTD('Table'[Date])
)
```